# When I use <localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html> the swagger screen does not appear. The image below appears

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

[The image below appears. The swagger screen does not appear. I'm a beginner, I've read many tutorials, but I can't find a solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjmRH.jpg)

I set up swagger like this:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

        @Bean
        public Docket productApi() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.eventos"))
                    .paths(regex("/evento.*"))
                    .build()
                    .apiInfo(metaData());
        }

        private ApiInfo metaData() {
            return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Spring Boot REST API")
            .description("\"Spring Boot REST API\"")
            .version("1.0.0")
            .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
            .licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\"")
            .build();}


        @Override
        protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. How do you configure Swagger in the Spring Boot app? Pls provide a snippet to show how Swagger is configured (in a Spring bean?)

Comment: There may be some issue in your APIs or Request DTOs. I also faced this. If there is some issue, swagger UI doesn’t load properly.